# Integrate validation into jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, ip-address

I have the following HTML/jQuery code that generates some links.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter text" autofocus />
<a id="link1" class="btn btn-info" href="#" target="_blank"> Search 1 </a>
<a id="link2" class="btn btn-info" href="#" target="_blank"> Search 2 </a>
<a id="link3" class="btn btn-info" href="#" target="_blank"> Search 3 </a>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var sel = document.getElementById('text');
        sel.onchange = function () {
            document.getElementById("link1").href = "http://example.com/action?queryString=" + this.value;
            document.getElementById("link2").href = "http://example.com/searchall.php?search=" + this.value;
            document.getElementById("link3").href = "http://example.com/dashboard.aspx?term=" + this.value;
            document.getElementById("text").focus();
        }
    };
</script>
```

On the 2nd search link, I'm looking to implement a change wherby if the value entered is an IP address, then the URI is changed. e.g.

```
document.getElementById("link2").href = "http://example.com/ipsearch.php?ip=" + this.value;
```

I just don't have a clue on where to start with this change.

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
sel.onchange = function () {
  var value = this.value;
  var isIP = /^(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)\.){3}([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|25[‌​0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$/.test(value);
  if (isIP) {
    document.getElementById("link2").href = "http://example.com/ipsearch.php?ip=" + value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("link2").href = "http://example.com/searchall.php?search=" + value
  }
};
```

This uses a regex to determine if an IP was entered, and if it was sets a different URL.